# Recovering a sheaf from base of topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, sheaf-theory

Exercise 2.5A in Vakil's notes suggests that one can recover information about a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ with just the information of what the sheaf gives on a base of topology $(\mathcal{F}(B_i), res_{B_i,B_j})$

My guess about how this works is the following:

To know any section $s \in \mathcal{F}(U)$ over an open $U$ is the same as knowing the stalk at every point in $p \in U$. So if we can determine $s_p$ for each $p$, we are done.

Now since stalks contain only local information, we can think of $s_p = (U, s) = (B_i, s|_{B_i})$ for some $B_i$. We have the latter, since we have the information about the sheaf on the base of topology, and so we are done.

This is what I had initially, but I ran into the following issues:

1. I'm using the information of $s$ (specifically, its restriction to $B_i$) to determine $s$, so the reasoning there seems circular.
2. I'm wary of taking stalks under different indexing sets. i.e. Is taking the stalk of $s$ and the direct limit over all open sets containing $p$ the same as taking the stalk of $s$ and the direct limit over all basis element sets containing $p$?

Regarding the first, issue, my best guess as to how to fix how I'm looking at this is to take the approach that to construct the sections in $\mathcal{F}(B_i \cup B_j)$, we need to see which germs in the stalks at points in the union are compatible. i.e. find $(s_p)_{p \in B_ij}$ such that for every $p$, there is a basis element $B$ containing $p$ in the union and a section $t \in \mathcal{F}(B)$ such that for each $q \in B$, we have $s_q = t_q$. If we can do this, then glue the compatible germs together to get a section $s$ on any union of base sets.

So my questions are as follows:

a) Is this latter approach correct? Would this be the most complete way to see what Vakil is trying to get at with this exercise? If so, could one point to a relatively simple example to see how this would work in practice.

b) Is my concern in issue 2) above well founded or am I missing something there?

Comment: I think you're barking up the wrong tree here. This subject has been covered here in the past, and I suspect that your post might be a duplicate - see for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86509/reference-for-it-is-enough-to-specify-a-sheaf-on-a-basis). The key idea is that you can specify the sections and restriction maps via the sheaf condition as an equalizer by covering any open set with elements from your base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually not necessary to use stalks at all. A sheaf is just a functor $P \in Sets^{\mathcal{O}_x^{op}}$ such that for all open covers $\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} U_i = U$, the diagram $P(U) \to \prod\limits_{k \in I} P(U_k) \rightrightarrows \prod\limits_{i \in I} \prod\limits_{j \in I} P(U_i \cap U_j)$ (with obvious arrows) is an equalizer.

Given a basis $B$, write $B_U = \{V \in B | V \subseteq U\}$. Then if $P$ is a sheaf, the following diagram must be an equalizer: $P(U) \to \prod\limits_{V \in B_U} P(V) \rightrightarrows \prod\limits_{Q \in B_U} \prod\limits_{R \in B_Q} P(R)$ (with obvious arrows). This follows from the definition of a sheaf and a bit of diagram chasing.

So now define a new functor $P'$. We define $P'(U)$ to be the (canonical) equalizer $P'(U) \to \prod\limits_{V \in B_U} P(V) \rightrightarrows \prod\limits_{Q \in B_U} \prod\limits_{R \in B_Q} P(R)$. Given that $T \subseteq U$, one can define a map $P'(U) \to P'(T)$ by taking the map $P'(U) \to \prod\limits_{V \in B_U} P(V) \to \prod\limits_{V \in B_T} P(V)$ and showing this map must factor through the equalizer $P'(T)$. From here, you must establish functoriality - this is pretty straightforward.

Finally, clearly each $P'(U)$ is isomorphic to $P(U)$ in a canonical way since both are equalizers of the same diagram. This isomorphism is natural.

So we have constructed a sheaf isomorphic to $P$ only using the restriction of $P$ to the basis.

Note that this result immediately generalizes to sheaves on a complete Heyting algebra (that is, a locale), since we only use the Heyting algebra structure of $\mathcal{O}_X$ and not any other properties of spaces. It also generalises to sheaves on an arbitrary site.

Comment: Interesting. This does make sense, though I think using stalks was a little bit more intuitive for me. I appreciate this though!

Comment: Amazing answer!