# Defining morphism of sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, affine-schemes

Suppose we have sheaves $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}$ on a topological space $X$ where $\mathcal{U}$ is a base of $X$. Then to define a morphism $\varphi:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{G}$, is it enough to define $\varphi(U): \mathcal{F}(U)\rightarrow \mathcal{G}(U)$ for each $U\in \mathcal{U}$? If so, if each defined $\varphi(U)$ is further an isomorphism, is $\varphi$ necessarily an isomorphism of sheaves?

These questions were kind of motivated by proofs of the isomorphism $(D(f), \mathcal{O}_X|_{D(f)})\cong (\operatorname{Spec}A_f, \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}_{A_f}})$ I read. It seems to me that when constructing the isomorphism of sheaves, people are only showing that they can define isomorphism of sections of these two sheaves on "basic opens" without constructing the general morphism of sheaves.

Comment: Yes and yes, as shown in the linked duplicates. Ravi Vakil's [Foundations of Algebraic Geometry](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf) also has material on this in section 2.5 if you're looking for an approach from a textbook.

Comment: Thank you! As a follow up question, what if we change sheaves to presheaves, are the results still true? Is there a reference for the presheaves case?

Comment: In the case you're asking about, [yes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86509/reference-for-it-is-enough-to-specify-a-sheaf-on-a-basis). Please endeavor to do a little more searching before asking next time.